# How to establish a server-to-server connection using Meteor?

Tags: meteor, subscription

Meteor itself has the possibility to [open a DDP connection to a DDP server](https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#DDP-connect) - also from the server - which I though was worth playing around with.

Meteor provides me with methods and subscriptions. Both can (speaking in the DDP context) only be started by and send data to the client.

How could I set up a connection from a meteor installation behind an NAT network (*that's the reason why it must be him setting up the connection*) to a meteor installation - let's say it's in the cloud - and let it subscribe to a dataset of the installation behind the NAT?

Only the client of the DDP communication can subscribe to a publication, published by the server, right - or is there a possibility missed out? It should more or less be like a pipeline or caching system having a subset of data, that sends changes back to the installation in the cloud.

Comment: Do I get it right, that you want the cloud app to subscribe to data of your NAT-internal app?

Comment: @Jankapunkt, that's right. The NAT-internal app is used just in case the network fully breaks down. It should actually forward the changes to the cloud app. The best way I could think of was - as you said - to let the NAT-internal app subscribe to the cloud app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, [the specification of the DDP protocol](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/ddp/DDP.md), which Meteor uses to exchange data, doesn't have an option to realize a solution like mine. It would have been nice though ...

I now either would have to extend DDP by the desired behavior or find another way.

I'd be happy if someone proofs my answer wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this usual way, unfortunately. Only client-side of connection can subscribe or call methods, not the vice-versa.

You can, though, use [`meteor-streamer`](https://github.com/RocketChat/meteor-streamer) package that allows you 2-way communication between client/server. Thus, you'll be able to organize needed observer inside your NAT-app and send notifications to your cloud app.

Comment: But `meteor-streamer` is only based on methods and subscriptions again, which doesn't really help here. What I'd need is really to stream data from the ddp-client to the ddp-server but on a scale where sending every single change via methods just isn't suitable. Thanks anyways for notifying me about it.